# Creating new Mailbox type using akka's java api-get a java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, groovy, akka, jvm-arguments

I'm integrating Akka 2.2.3(using it's Java API) into a Java/Groovy Spring project.  All has been going well, but after creating a custom Mailbox type(one based on a bounded priority queue) I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/test/pricing/transformer/spring/WorkerPriorityMailbox, method: <init> signature: (Lakka/actor/ActorSystem$Settings;Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:76)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookupConfigurator(Mailboxes.scala:195)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookup(Mailboxes.scala:78)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getMailboxType(Mailboxes.scala:154)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:718)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:338)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:520)
    at akka.actor.ActorRefFactory$actorOf.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```

Thinking this was a classloader issue, I've excluded duplicate libs in my maven pom so there is only one instance of scala-lib, akka-actor, and akka-kernel...but that didn't solve the issue.  I also toggled the JVM version I was targeting from 1.6 to 1.7 and that had no effect.  I then kept looking at the custom mailbox type, to see if I was doing something wrong there:

```
public class WorkerPriorityMailbox extends BoundedPriorityMailbox {
  // needed for reflective instantiation
  public WorkerPriorityMailbox(ActorSystem.Settings settings, Config config) {
    // Create a new PriorityGenerator, lower prio means more important
    //java.util.Comparator<akka.dispatch.Envelope> cmp, int capacity, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration pushTimeOut
    super(new PriorityGenerator() {
      @Override
      public int gen(Object message) {
        if (message == Msg.FULL)
          return 0; // high priority messages should be treated first if possible
        else if (message.equals(Msg.DELTA))
          return 1; // 'lowpriority messages should be treated last if possible
        else if (message.equals(PoisonPill.getInstance()))
          return 3; // PoisonPill when no other left
        else
          return 2; //other message types
      }
    }, 100, new FiniteDuration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  }

  /*public MessageQueue create(Option<ActorRef> owner, Option<ActorSystem> system) {
    return new WorkerPriorityMailbox();
  } */

}
```

here is the configuration:

```
 priority-full-over-delta-mailboxtype {
          mailbox-type = "com.example.pricing.transformer.spring.WorkerPriorityMailbox"
            mailbox-capacity = 1000
          //Other dispatcher configuration goes here
        }
```

and here's the code that creates the actors:

```
system.actorOf(Props.create(new WorkerActorCreator(applicationContext, it.start, it.end)).withMailbox("priority-full-over-delta-mailboxtype"))
```

I don't think it's relevant as it worked before editing the mailbox type, but here's the code to WorkerActorCreator(it applies spring annotations to the created actor):

```
class WorkerActorCreator implements akka.japi.Creator<WorkerActor>{
    ApplicationContext applicationContext
    Long start
    Long end
    public WorkerActorCreator(ApplicationContext ac, Long start, Long end)
    {
      applicationContext = ac
      this.start = start
      this.end = end

    }
    @Override
    WorkerActor create() throws Exception {
      println("creating workerT")
      WorkerActor worker = new WorkerActor(start, end)
      applicationContext.autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(worker)
      worker
    }

  }
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

EDIT:  When running the application with `-Xverify:none` it did work, but I'm not sure this is a long term solution...

Comment: Wow, thanks for the VM's argument. At least something!